# Issue with Istio 1.3.5 and communicating with azure event hub using kafa compatibility

Tags: kubernetes, istio

So we are running istio 1.3.5

We have a docker container running a dotnet core application that is trying to consume messages from azure event hub.

With the istio sidecar turned on, we get a 404, with it turned off things work just fine.

Also interesting is you can send messages to the event hub just fine with the sidecar enabled.

here's the istio related yaml that's "in play" in the namespace:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  egress:
  - hosts:
    - "./*"
    - "elasticsearch/*"
```

```
apiVersion: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
kind: "DestinationRule"
metadata:
  name: "default"
spec:
  host: "*.MYNAMESPACE_NAME.svc.cluster.local"
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

```
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: "default"
spec:
  peers:
  - mtls: {}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors if you use `kubectl describe` on your pod? Can you post some yaml? I think people are going to need more information to go on in order to help.  Can you edit your question to provide more details?

Comment: Details added to the description.

Comment: What you mean by `docker container running`? Kubernetes deployment? I assume event hub is external service so did you add a [service entry](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) for it, so istio injected apps could talk with not injected apps?

Answer (score 2):

We have figured out the issue.
When the istio sidecar and the main micro service startup, there is a period of time where the istio sidecar is initializing itself and is not “on”.
During this period all network traffic from the main microservice is blocked.
**To fix this you need to make a call to an istio sidecar endpoint before your main program starts.**

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    until curl  --head localhost:15000   
    do  
       echo "Waiting for Sidecar"  
       sleep 3   
    done   
    
    echo "Sidecar available"
```